# Shared Doctrine EntityManager service

Tags: doctrine-orm

We are using Symfony for our projects and there's something about Doctrine that I can't get on with.
Doctrine's entity manager (lets call it 'em' in the following) is a shared service, so when I inject em into multiple services, they share exactly the same instance of em. It is simpler If I introduce an example right away to explain what I want to ask: Consider the following example:

```php
$service1 = $this->get('vendor_test.service_one'); // $service1 has a private entity manager property
$service2 = $this->get('vendor_test.service_two'); // $service2 as well has a private entity manager property

$entity1 = $service1->getEntityById(1); // getEntityById() queries for an entity with the given id and returns it. So it is in the managed list of service1's entity manager
$entity2 = $service2->getEntityById(2); // entity1 and entity2 not necessarily of the same class

$entity1
   ->setProperty1('aaaa')
   ->setProperty2($service2->updateDateTime($entity2))  // updateDateTime() let's say updates a datetime field of the passed entity (in this case entity2) and calls $this->entityManager->flush(); and returns the datetime.
   ->setProperty3('bbbb')

$service1->save();  // calls $this->entityManager->flush() so it should update the managed entities (in this case entity1)
```

So the question is: If the entityManager object of service1 and service2 are the same instance of entityManager so they are identical, they share the same internal managed list, then when calling `$service2->updateDateTime($entity2)` does an `entityManager->flush()`, does it flushes $entity1 as well? Does $entity1 with Property1 set to 'aaaa' being flushed midway and updated in the database, and being flushed in a second step when $service1->save(); is called?

Hope I managed to draw up what I mean and what I want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

As I tested out and asked someone more competent, the answer is yes, since everywhere I use entity manager they all share the same managed list. To overcome the problem mentioned in the question, is to pass the entity to be flushed to the entity manager and all the others will be intact.